# Assume that $F(n) = n^2$is the summatory function of $f$. Compute $f(63, 000, 000).$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Assume that $F(n) = n^2$ is the summatory function of $f$. Compute $f(63, 000, 000).$

I know that $F(n)=\sum\limits_{d\mid n}f(d)=(63, 000, 000)^2$

I know the prime factors of $n=2^6×3^2×5^6×7$

I'm not seeing how to find $f(n)$ though

Edit: Using the hint from the comments I use the defenition of the mobius inversion

$f(n)=\sum\limits_{d \mid n} \mu(d)F(\frac{n}{d})$

From above all the factors go to $0$ from the dentition so the only one you have to calculate is $7$ so I get $-9,000,000$

Comment: [Möbius inversion?](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%B6bius_inversion_formula)

Comment: Oh I must have missed that definition I think I can do it now.